# Firebase-admin-python: configure message so that it will be received in background by Android device

Tags: python, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have a celery task that sends messages to my client via firebase-admin. In development I used to send notifications like this and it all worked fine (my React-Native app received messages both in foreground and in background as expected):

```
message = messaging.Message(
        data={
            'text': msg.text,
        },
        token=registration_token,
    )

response = messaging.send(message)
```

But after the release my Android device refused to receive a message in background unless its priority is set to 'high'. And apparently I can't just add a 'priority' key to my old simple configuration (I tried and got a ValueError: Message.android must be an instance of Android.config class). So I found an example of how to set priority in firebase-admin [docs](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/blob/28c4d46d0e7f0378b8d88ab821f6f746ae11564f/snippets/messaging/cloud_messaging.py#L24-L40):

```
def android_message():
# [START android_message]
message = messaging.Message(
    android=messaging.AndroidConfig(
        ttl=datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
        priority='normal',
        notification=messaging.AndroidNotification(
            title='$GOOG up 1.43% on the day',
            body='$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 1.43% on the day.',
            icon='stock_ticker_update',
            color='#f45342'
        ),
    ),
    topic='industry-tech',
)
# [END android_message]
return message
```

Now my question is, how do I set registration token in this more elaborate message config? Is the token going somewhere else now? I guess I'm missing something very obvious here, so will appreciate any help and hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample you found send the message to a topic, which is a named key that clients can subscribe to. So no token is needed to send here, as it's a public/subscribe delivery system.

If you want to deliver to a specific token, replace the `topic` key with `token` as shown in this example from the documentation on [sending messages to specific devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices):

```
# This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
registration_token = 'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN'

 # See documentation on defining a message payload.
message = messaging.Message(
    data={
        'score': '850',
        'time': '2:45',
    },
    token=registration_token,
)

# Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
# registration token.
response = messaging.send(message)
# Response is a message ID string.
print('Successfully sent message:', response)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was only logical and it worked! :)